# Save partial data from external function as global variable in xcode

Tags: swift, variables, urlsession

I am calling an external function from my main ViewController, but the external function is designed to print only.

The function includes some URLsession data called megabytesPerSecond that i want to save as a variable in my main ViewController, but I cannot get that bit of information into a variable that is recognizable in my main viewcontroller.

```
connectedSpeed().testDownloadSpeedWithTimout(timeout: 5.0) { (megabytesPerSecond, error) -> () in
    if ((error == nil) && isReachable && !needsConnection) {
        if megabytesPerSecond!>=0.05 {
            //print("\n       | Connected |")
            print("=======Network Speed=======\nMBps: \(megabytesPerSecond!)\nerror: \(String(describing: error))\n=======-------------=======\n")
        }else{
            //print("\n       ? Connected ?")
            print("*======| WEAK SIGNAL |======*\nMBps: \(megabytesPerSecond!)\nerror: \(String(describing: error))\n*=======-------------=======*\n")
        }
    }else{
        print("NETWORK ERROR: \(String(describing: error))")

        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the code in the code block.

Comment: When you say "I cannot get that bit of information into a variable that is recognizable in my main viewcontroller", do you get some sort of error from the compiler?

Comment: @JohnV xcode says "Expression implicitly coerced from 'Double?' to Any" when calling "megabytesPerSecond" And the debugger prints my value as so: "Optional(numbers)".  Aside from figuring out the coercion, I want to take the function that this code exists in, call it in my main viewcontroller, and be able to use it anytime, like this? <br/> 'myFunction()  <br/> let x = megabytesPerSecond'